# Independence of survey questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I'm working with some survey data, similar in format to the following:

1. Which of the following is your favorite color?

   A1: Blue
   A2: Black
   A3: Red
   A4: Green
   A5: Yellow
   A6: Orange
2. What grade are you in?

   A1: 1st
   A2: 2nd
   A3: 3rd

I want to see if these questions are dependent somehow (i.e., a 3rd grader would be more likely to answer red than yellow, etc.). Currently, I've computed a frequency table and am taking a paired t-test between the expected distributions (based on the frequency of each response separately). Do you have any recommendations on material to read or methods to look into?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You have two categorical variables (*color* and *grade*) and if you are looking for the association between them (and if you take *grade* as nominal), you can use Pearson's chi-squared test. It is not clear for me why you used t-test, since you are not testing the mean difference. You can learn more by searching `correlation` and `categorical-data` tags on this site.

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2):

With this kind of data, you can just run a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).  From your responses, you can count the number of kids in each grade who have each favorite color.  This will give you 18 counts, in your case.  These are entered into a 6 (row) x 3 (column) contingency table.

```
    Year
Color    1st  2nd  3rd
  Blue     9   13   16
  Black    2    3  ...
  Red     11  ...
  Green  ...
  Yellow 
  Orange
```

From there, you could conduct the test.

One thing to watch out for is whether you end up with cells with low expected counts.  This could occur if few kids are in a particular grade and few like a particular color.  You don't want any cells with *expected* counts <1, or more than 3 with expected counts <5.  If you do have that, you should try to simulate the sampling distribution.  Statistical software often makes that easy to do.